# How to add menu to Dashboard that can be viewed by all users

Tags: menus, admin, dashboard

I am able to add Menu to the Dashboard using the below code, it can be viewed by an administrator. That menu doesn't appear when logged in as an Author or a Subscriber. How to make sure every user can view the custom added menus.

```
//Add Menu Page


add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );

function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
add_dashboard_page( 'custom menu title', 'Test', 'manage_options', 'custompage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'test/images/icon.png' ), 6 ); 
}


function my_custom_menu_page(){
echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"></div>';
    echo '<h2>Test</h2>';
    echo 'Test';

echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the right [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) for this. You chose [`manage_options`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#manage_options), which by default only users with an [Administrator](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator) user role have.

So, change it to `read` or `exist`, for instance, and **every** user will be able to see and access the menu.

```
add_dashboard_page( 'custom menu title', 'Test', 'read', 'custompage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'test/images/icon.png' ), 6 );
```